# Переменная $_user

Tags: php, yii2, yii, php7

Есть следующий код взятый [отсюда](https://github.com/samdark/yiipowered/blob/0890fe11a354cf7a5b4a6b79ea5f6ee38aa7f2c0/models/LoginForm.php):

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * Login form
 *
 * @property \app\models\User|null $user
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;

    private $_user = false;


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'username' => Yii::t('app', 'Username'),
            'password' => Yii::t('app', 'Password'),
        ];
    }


    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();
            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, Yii::t('user', 'Incorrect username or password.'));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     *
     * @return boolean whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), 3600 * 24 * 30);
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

Помогите разобраться - зачем нужна переменная `$_user` ([18 строка кода](https://github.com/samdark/yiipowered/blob/0890fe11a354cf7a5b4a6b79ea5f6ee38aa7f2c0/models/LoginForm.php#L18))?
Что она делает и какую функцию выполняет в этом коде? Почему название этой переменной начинается со знака нижнего подчеркивания?

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего это чисто для тестов. Чисто посмотреть работает форма или нет.  Чтобы юзер не искался в БД и чтобы не валидировался пароль. Чтобы можно просто на сайт свободно войти пока разрабатываешь.

Нижнее подчёркивание - это из прошлых времён, когда по соглашению приватные свойства начинали с этого знака. Чтобы в коде сразу можно было отличить их от публичных. ИМХО нет особого смысла. Но кто-то использует